# Filter deep object based on checkbox input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, but my filter hides all itineraries in my itinerary object.

My object looks like so (they are quite big so I will just show you the structure):

```
[
    { // itinerary
         filters:{
              stops:2
         }
         ... children
    },
    {
         ... next itinerary
    }
]
```

My ngRepeat looks like this

```
<div class="col-sm-12 item" data-ng-repeat="itinerary in results | filter: {itinerary: {filters: {stops: filterStops}}} | orderBy: orderBy" data-ng-class="{ active: resultDetails }">
```

I am setting my filterStops scope item like so

```
md-checkbox aria-label="Non-Stop" data-ng-model="filterStops" ng-true-value="0">Direct</md-checkbox>
```

Nothing is displayed in any situation, whether I hardcode the number of stop into the filter directly, or whether I select it via the checkbox. No Console errors to speak of, I am guessing my logic to reach the sub property in the filters object is flawed?

I am at a loss here, any help appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you expand the code a wee bit into a [mcve] (possibly also *remove* irrelevant code, e.g. the bootstrap classes are probably not needed to repro?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in controller

```
$scope.filter=function(obj){
  return obj.filters.stops == $scope.resultDetails;
}
```

Add this to view

```
data-ng-repeat="itinerary in results | filter: filter | orderBy: orderBy"
```

Comment: That works pretty well, thank you.  is there no way to do this purely in the partial? I just felt it would be cleaner to not have a number filtr functions in my Controller, but happy to do it if it's considered best practice I guess. Thank you again!

Comment: If this will be used in other places then it's best practice to write custom filter like this https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09 @Dbrandt

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. That was going to be my fallback, as I had that working previously. Thank you for your time.